# Find the value for the derivative of the following function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Literally from textbook [1]:

> If $y = (x^3 + 9)^{17/2}$, find $y'|_{x = 2}$.

Differentiate using the chain rule:

$$y' = \frac{17}{2}(x^3 + 9)^{15/2} \displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}(x^3 + 9) = \frac{17}{2}(x^3 + 9)^{15/2} \ 3x^2 = \frac{51}{2}x^2(x^3 + 9)^{15/2}$$

Substitute $x = 2$ in $y'$:

$$\displaystyle y'|_{x = 2} = \frac{51}{2}(2)^2((2)^3 + 9)^{15/2} = \frac{51}{2}  4 \ (8 + 9)^{15/2} = \frac{204}{2} \ (17)^{15/2} = 102 \ (17)^{15/2}$$

Not really a 'nice' number and checking the answers tells me it should be just $102$. So, I checked my derivative using wolfram-alpha.com, but that seems fine.

Am I misinterpreting the exercise? And if so, how should I read it differently?

[1] Adams, Essex. Calculus a complete course, 7th edition

Comment: May be a typo in the book: You get $y'(-2)=102$

Comment: Yep, typo on my part. There are some pen marks just crossing the $x=A$ part in the book, should indeed be $x = -2$.